# Import MySQL Spatial vector layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, mysql

I have a spatial table called 'places' in MySQL, with a spatial column 'pt' (point). I tried to import it in QGIS and no points appear. I created a view 'places_as_text' which reproduces the table but shows the points as WKT (used astext(pt) in the definition of the view). Still nothing appears in QGIS.

Any help appreciated

Comment: How did you try to add the spatial table? Like described in http://getspatial.com/gisblog/qgis-vector-data-connection?

Comment: Yes, and I also tried through python as explained here: http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/loadlayer.html the result is the same. My spatial column, astext, has values that look like that: 'POINT(249386 371818)'

Answer (score 4):

I'm using MySQL spatial tables everyday with QGIS in r&w mode using

> Add Vector > Database > Type: MySQL

and defining a new connection, just like described in http://getspatial.com/gisblog/qgis-vector-data-connection. I can connect both to local and remote server.
I'm not using the original geometry definition and not converting it to WKT. Do you have any connection problem (what is the result of test connection)?

Check also your table structure: field type MUST be GEOMETRY otherwise QGIS will load the table as attribute table and will not show any vector!

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will try and update, but the data is not that easy to access at the moment

Comment: It seems that this has been removed in QGIS 2.0 ...