# How to connect QGIS to an online database on Mac OS X?

Tags: qgis, database, web, mac

I'm a real beginner/dummy when it comes to QGIS and online databases. I have tried a variety of things trying to connect to Spatialite, PostGIS and MySQL but all attempts have failed due to my lack of knowledge on the subject.

So I was wandering:

- What is the easiest way to connect QGIS to an online database?
- Is there such a thing as a step by step manual to do this that is easy to understand by non programmers and dummies like myself?

Many thanks for your help

Ed

specs:
MAC OS X Mountain Lion (but I also have Ubuntu)

QGIS 1.8 Lisboa

Comment: If you already tried to connect to PostGIS, can you post the window with your connection definition so we can try to point out possible error sources?

Answer (score 0):

QGIS has default support for PostGIS. PostGIS is PostGreSQL with spatial types and procedures to handle them. Using PostGIS from QGIS from any platform should be pretty much the same whether you are using Linux, Windows or MacOSX.

This website provides information about how you can connect to PostGIS from QGIS:

- [GIStutor on connecting to PostGIS layers using QGIS](http://www.gistutor.com/quantum-gis/20-intermediate-quantum-gis-tutorials/34-working-with-your-postgis-layers-using-quantum-gis-qgis.html)

There are also some plugins available which will allow you to connect to other databases. Relevant links:

- [MySQL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14486/import-mysql-spatial-vector-layer-in-qgis)
- [MSSQL 2008](http://www.mapsolutions.com.au/news/quantum-gis-new-version-mssql2008-support.aspx)

Google around and I am sure you will find other solutions as well :-)

Regards,

Ragnvald