# QGIS 2.0 without MySQL connector

Tags: qgis, gdal, ogr, mysql, connection

On a mac (Mountain Lion), after a major upgrade to GDAL (1.10) and related frameworks from KyngChaos page, QGIS 2.0 doesn't show any MySQL connector:

> Add Vector > Database > ...

The driver doesn't appear neither in the terminal running the "ogr2ogr --formats" command.
I read ([link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14486/import-mysql-spatial-vector-layer-in-qgis)), at the very end of the post, that this feature has been removed from QGIS 2.0. Anyway, it appears to me that it depends on GDAL/OGR: it seems that the framework has been build without MySQL support.

Comment: on my, does not work.
when I try to open the database qgis crash Process: QGIS [53751] Path: /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS Identifier: org.qgis.qgis Version: 2.2.0 (2.2.0 []) Code Type: X86-64 (Native) Parent Process: launchd [276] Responsible: QGIS [53751] User ID: 501 Date/Time: 2014-03-17 10:33:37.731 +0000 OS Version: Mac OS X 10.9.2 (13C64) Report Version: 11 Anonymous UUID: 210BA7B3-460E-3614-9E8A-1E836F758714 Sleep/Wake UUID: BCF76B4E-5922-4758-B01A-96F78B8E247E Crashed Thread: 0 Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:

Comment: I think previous comment was intended as a response to the posted answer, not the question itself. I followed the steps in the answer (except that I did not edit any files as in step 4 and I used gdal-1.11.3) and ran into same exception - segmentation fault EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't look like it is included in the most recent [GDAL-Complete framework](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks). Please file a request with kyngchaos.com.

In the meantime, if you don't mind trying it yourself, you can attempt to build a shared plugin for GDAL 1.10, install it, and see if it works with your data source:

1. Ensure you have XCode and/or its command line tools installed.
2. Download and install [latest MySQL Community Server](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) (installs to `/usr/local/mysql`).
3. Download [the GDAL source](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadSource) and un-archive to folder, e.g. `gdal-1.10.1`, and enter it.

   ```
   $ cd /path/to/gdal-1.10.1
   ```
4. Edit a single source file and comment-out unsupported symbols in MySQL 5.6+ client

   `ogr/ogrsf_frmts/mysql/ogrmysqldatasource.cpp @ line 130`

   ```
   /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
   /*      Use options process to get .my.cnf file contents.               */
   /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
       int nPort = 0, i;
       char **papszTableNames=NULL;
       std::string oHost, oPassword, oUser, oDB;
   //     char *apszArgv[2] = { (char*) "org", NULL };
   //     char **papszArgv = apszArgv;
   //     int  nArgc = 1;
   //     const char *client_groups[] = {"client", "ogr", NULL };

       my_init(); // I hope there is no problem with calling this multiple times!
   //     load_defaults( "my", client_groups, &nArgc, &papszArgv );
   // 
   //     for( i = 0; i < nArgc; i++ )
   //     {
   //         if( EQUALN(papszArgv[i],"--user=",7) )
   //             oUser = papszArgv[i] + 7;
   //         else if( EQUALN(papszArgv[i],"--host=",7) )
   //             oHost = papszArgv[i] + 7;
   //         else if( EQUALN(papszArgv[i],"--password=",11) )
   //             oPassword = papszArgv[i] + 11;
   //         else if( EQUALN(papszArgv[i],"--port=",7) )
   //             nPort = atoi(papszArgv[i] + 7);
   //     }
   // 
   //     // cleanup
   //     free_defaults( papszArgv );
   ```
5. Build shared plugin, in Terminal:

   ```
   # make directory for build output
   $ mkdir ogr_plugins

   # compile shared plugin, statically linking in libmysqlclient (multi-line, single command)
   $ g++ -Wall -g ogr/ogrsf_frmts/mysql/*.c* \
   -shared -o ogr_plugins/ogr_MySQL.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.a \
   -Iport -Igcore -Iogr -Iogr/ogrsf_frmts -Iogr/ogrsf_frmts/mysql \
   -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/mysql/include \
   -framework GDAL -lz -install_name ogr_MySQL.dylib

   */ #just closing comment for SE syntax highlighting 

   # copy plugin to known GDAL_DRIVER_PATH (sudo needed)
   $ cd ogr_plugins
   $ sudo cp -f ogr_MySQL.dylib /Library/Application\ Support/GDAL/1.10/PlugIns/
   ```
6. Verify plugin:

   ```
   $ cd /path/to/gdal-1.10.1
   $ otool -L ogr_plugins/ogr_MySQL.dylib
   ogr_plugins/ogr_MySQL.dylib:
           ogr_MySQL.dylib (...)
           /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/GDAL (...)
           /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (...)
           /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (...)
           /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (...)

   $ ogrinfo --formats | grep 'MySQL'
   -> "MySQL" (read/write)
   ```
7. Launch QGIS and verify plugin loading in PyQGIS console:

   ```
   from osgeo import ogr
   sorted([ogr.GetDriver(drv).name for drv in range(0,ogr.GetDriverCount())])
   ```
8. You should be able to connect to a MySQL data source via `Add Vector > Database > ...` now.

*Please note, I don't have any geospatial MySQL data sources, so was unable to test the plugin I built.*

Comment: I can test the plugin (and the method as well) with a MySQL geospatial point table. It works!

Comment: dakcarto, your answer works through QGIS 2.14.3 (KyngChaos) but breaks at 2.18.0 when GDAL is migrated to 2.1 from 1.10.1. I've tried to use your methodology, but I failed. Do you mind taking another look?