# Import MySQL data to QGIS with a plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, mysql

Does anyone know about a plugin that can import a MySQL database into QGIS?

Answer (score 6):

The only plugins I know that involve databases in QGIS are:

- DB Manager
- SQL Anywhere plugin
- eVis

You can also import MySQL layers directly via:

*Layer* > *Add Vector Layer...* > select *Database* and your type.

[image]

Comment: I don't see the MySQL in my dropdown. I am running 2.10.1-Pisa on a mac. Is there some plugin you have to install to get MySQL in the dropdown?

Comment: @morpheus - I don't think you _should_ have to but can't confirm this for mac (I use Windows). Perhaps the following post might help: [Installing GDAL and QGIS on OSX Yosemite](http://scottdavey.net/article/Installing-GDAL-and-QGIS-on-OSX-Yosemite-231); [QGIS 2.0 without MySQL connector](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74367/qgis-2-0-without-mysql-connector)

Comment: reading elsewhere I found that this feature (ability to read from MySQL) was removed in QGIS 2.0, so that is why I seem to be missing MySQL in the dropdown.

Comment: @morpheus - Huh, that's rather unfortunate. Wonder why it was removed. I noticed you asked a new question regarding this so hopefully you will get some answers ;)