# Import non spatial data from MySQL DB into QGIS using queries

Tags: qgis, mysql

I want to import data from MySQL DB.
MySQL schema has a lot of tables with a huge amount of data. This is non spatial data. I want to import objects as vector layers using sql query which is selecting and joining only what I need.
Is it possible to do?

I`ve tried to use Layer->Add Vector Layer ...> MySQL database. But QGIS get crashed in this case ([Import MySQL data to QGIS with a plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113979/import-mysql-data-to-qgis-with-a-plugin)).
Indeed, my db has not vector data, it has only tables with longitude, latitude columns.

I`ve tried to use DB Manager plugin but its help says that only four predefined dbms backends are supported ([db_manager github](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/python/plugins/db_manager)) and no MySQL DBMS listed there.

Comment: Is your spatial data in same same database? If yes , then create view data as select * from spatialdata left join moredata and create layer from it 

or export table as csv , import it with delimited text layer (select no geometry) and do join in layer properties. 

I dont see anyother options with mysql, postgresql and other databases have better support in qgis, maybe move data to postgresql for spatial analysis ?

Comment: I have not any spatial data in the db. Only tables with and without coordinates of points.

Comment: Anyway thank you. Will try to get csv from mysql with python script inside QGIS and then import it as a layer.