# Problem loading from MySQL in QGIS 2.10 on Mac

Tags: qgis, ogr, mysql

I cannot load a vector layer from MySQL in QGIS 2.10 (Pisa) on a Mac. If I goto Layer -> Add Layer -> Add Vector Layer -> Database I do not see MySQL in the drop down.

[image]

I found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/74380/10914) link. I did not go through all the steps in that answer. Rather I jumped to step 6 where it says to run `ogrinfo --formats`. This is what I got:

```
$ ogrinfo
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ogrinfo
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

After some mucking around I found that I already have a similar file at:

```
$ ls /usr/local/mysql/lib
libmysqlclient.20.dylib libmysqld-debug.a   mecab
libmysqlclient.a    libmysqld.a     pkgconfig
libmysqlclient.dylib    libmysqlservices.a  plugin
```

I had installed MySQL from a DMG file if that helps. I copied all these files recursively to `/usr/local/opt/mysql/lib` and also renamed `libmysqlclient.20.dylib` to `linmysqlclient.18.lib` to end up with following:

```
$ ls /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib
libmysqlclient.18.dylib libmysqld-debug.a   mecab
libmysqlclient.a    libmysqld.a     pkgconfig
libmysqlclient.dylib    libmysqlservices.a  plugin
```

Now I get:

```
$ ogrinfo --formats | grep 'MySQL'
  -> "MySQL" (read/write)
```

But Step 7 of the answer does not work as expected:

```
>>> from osgeo import ogr
>>> sorted([ogr.GetDriver(drv).name for drv in range(0,ogr.GetDriverCount())])
['ARCGEN', 'AVCBin', 'AVCE00', 'AeronavFAA', 'BNA', 'CSV', 'CartoDB', 'CouchDB', 'DGN', 'DODS', 'DXF', 'EDIGEO', 'ESRI Shapefile', 'ElasticSearch', 'GFT', 'GME', 'GML', 'GMT', 'GPKG', 'GPSBabel', 'GPSTrackMaker', 'GPX', 'GeoJSON', 'GeoRSS', 'Geoconcept', 'Geomedia', 'HTF', 'Idrisi', 'Interlis 1', 'Interlis 2', 'KML', 'LIBKML', 'MSSQLSpatial', 'MapInfo File', 'Memory', 'NAS', 'ODBC', 'ODS', 'OGDI', 'OSM', 'OpenAir', 'OpenFileGDB', 'PCIDSK', 'PDS', 'PGDump', 'PGeo', 'PostgreSQL', 'REC', 'S57', 'SDTS', 'SEGUKOOA', 'SEGY', 'SOSI', 'SQLite', 'SUA', 'SVG', 'SXF', 'TIGER', 'UK .NTF', 'VFK', 'VRT', 'WAsP', 'WFS', 'Walk', 'XLS', 'XLSX', 'XPlane']
```

MySQL is not listed in above. What am I missing here? Tried running QGIS again and don't see MySQL in the drop down. Any help?

I have also tried copying `mysqlclient.20.lib` to `/Library/Application\ Support/GDAL/1.11/PlugIns/` with no success.

Answer (score 1):

You've to reinstall `mysql` and `ogrinfo` package to fix the broken dependencies, e.g.

```
brew reinstall mysql ogrinfo
```

Also make sure you're not overriding any `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` or `DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH` variables from the startup shell scripts (e.g. `~/.bash_profile`).

Answer (score 0):

After following all the steps in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/74380/10914) answer (except that I did not edit any files as in step 4 and I used gdal-1.11.3) I was able to get past this issue but ran into a new problem. I see the mysql dropdown now but when I try to connect to a db I get a segmentation fault EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Answer (score 0):

While researching this issue I found this:http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/MySQL-support-Qgis-on-Mac-td5215360.html 
Which may be the answer if one is using kyngchaos on OS X