# MySQL select linestrings into a multilinestring

Tags: mysql, linestring, mysql-spatial

I have a mysql column of linestring type with 2000 linestrings (high water mark values to be more specific).

I want to merge them into one multilinestring so i can see what the shape of these values are in MySQL workbench spatial viewer or somewhere else.

Is there a mysql function that can join all the linestrings into a linestring or any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a spatial function called [`ST_Union`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-operator-functions.html#function_st-union) that would help, but you may not have the right version of MySQL to use it.

Here's a way that you can manipulate the WKT directly using `GROUP_CONCAT`.  It will allow you to create a `MULTILINESTRING`.  Alternatively, you could create a `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION` the same way.

Note that you may run out of memory, so have a look at the `group_concat_max_len` variable.

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 99999; 

use test_gdb;


CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `geom` GEOMETRY NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

INSERT INTO `test`
  (`geom`)
VALUES
  (LineStringFromText('LINESTRING(0 0,1 1,2 2,3 3,4 4)')),
  (LineStringFromText('LINESTRING(5 5,6 6,7 7,8 8,9 9)'));


SELECT
    GeomFromText(CONCAT('MULTILINESTRING(', GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(AsText(`geom`), 'LINESTRING', '')), ')'))
FROM 
    `test`;

DROP TABLE `test`;
```

I suppose an alternative to all this would be to view the table in QGIS directly:

[Import MySQL Spatial vector layer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14486/import-mysql-spatial-vector-layer-in-qgis)

Comment: Ok, so apparently our version of mysql does support st_union.

All the linestrings are on lgate0832feature.thegeom

If I do


`select st_union(thegeom) from lgate083feature LIMIT 0, 1000 
`
I get 

Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'st_union' 0.089 sec

I can do

`SELECT
    CONCAT('MULTILINESTRING(', GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(AsText(`thegeom`), 'LINESTRING', '')), ')')
FROM 
    `lgate083feature`;`

Comment: Ok, so apparently our version of mysql does support st_union.

All the linestrings are on lgate0832feature.thegeom

If I do


`select st_union(thegeom) from lgate083feature LIMIT 0, 1000 
`
I get 

Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'st_union' 0.089 sec

I can do

`SELECT
    CONCAT('MULTILINESTRING(', GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(AsText(`thegeom`), 'LINESTRING', '')), ')')
FROM 
    `lgate083feature`;`

To get the values as a string but i would like to get them as a geometry so the spatial viewer of this mysqlworkbench here renders the data

Comment: You need to use the `GeomFromText` function.  See the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the GeoFromText is not working for me or the concatenated MultiLineString text is not well formed. If I run `SELECT
    CONCAT('MULTILINESTRING(', GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(AsText(`thegeom`), 'LINESTRING', '')), ')')
FROM 
    linksregister.lgate083feature;` I get a multilinestring text, but if i wrap it into `GeomFromText` as in `SELECT
    GeomFromText(CONCAT('MULTILINESTRING(', GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(AsText(`thegeom`), 'LINESTRING', '')), ')'))
FROM 
    linksregister.lgate083feature` I get a null